# FIlter by populated object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi I have a collection A:

```
{
  "id":ObjectId('637cb32dfc225ac6c1f491e9')
  "job": ObjectId('636cb6f85ad34855281448db')
  "publicUrl": "22e0c7ef-d58b-44b7-93d1-7989b6f1bb2c",
}
```

And the *job* collection is as fellow:

```
{
 id:ObjectId('636cb6f85ad34855281448db')
  "name": "Intern",
    "users": [
    ObjectId("626a4d697586ac8cac88425a"),
    ObjectId("63c0099f41053d5dc529f1b9"),
  ]
}
```

I want to gell all A collections so that I only get the ones where user is in the "users" array of the job collection

This is what I've done so far but I'm getting 0 records.

```
const userId= mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId);
const reports= await Reports.find({ active: true,'job.users._id': { $in: [ userId ] }}).populate({ path: 'status', select: 'name position' }) .populate({ path: 'job', select: 'name users' });;
```

What Am I doing wrong  ?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup):

```
const userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId);
const reports = await Reports.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: { // Aggregate operation
      from: 'jobs',
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            users: userId, // If not match, it still returns empty job, that's why we need the skip operation below
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'job'
    }
  }
  , {
    $match: { // Skip operation: 
      "job": { $ne: [] }
    }
  }
]);
```